# How can m.2 usb 3.0 devices power an m.2 ssd?

Tags: usb, ssd, power, adapter, m.2

All these devices claim to be downwards compatible with usb 3.0 or even usb 2.0. How can they power up m.2 pci ssds which can consume up to 9W (checked with smartmontools) if usb 3.0 gives a maximum of 900mA and 5V?

Comment: Probably because not every PCI SSD uses 9W, and not every USB port limits power to 900mA

Comment: So there may be cases where they fail to work, right?

Comment: Seems that way. You can't defy physics.